# Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND not supported by

Tags: dcm4che

When querying the `dcm4chee PACS Server` using `dcm4chee` tools I am getting the following error message from the `PACS server`:

```
ERROR - 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND not supported byResolutionMD

org.dcm4che2.net.NoPresentationContextException: 

1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND not supported byResolutionMD.
```

Can someone kindly indicate what may be the cause of this error message?

Thanks
Goktug

Answer (score 2):

Did you change the AE title of DCM4CHEE? It looks like you are querying a system with AE title of "byResolutionMD" (which is not the default AET for a DCM4CHEE archive).

See also, http://forums.dcm4che.org/jiveforums/thread.jspa?messageID=12227

Comment: Thanks. You could mark it correct if it solved your issue or at least up vote if it was useful.